# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in created VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      channels: channelz.Root.Channels.Channel,
      currentIndex: 1,
      columnNumber: 9,
      rowNumber:7,
      windows: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    }
    };
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    this.handleResize();
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize() {
      this.windows.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.windows.height = window.innerHeight;
      this.checkColumnNumber();
      this.checkRowNumber();
    },
    checkColumnNumber(){
      var calcCol= 0;
        for(var i = 1;i < this.channels.length;i++){
          calcCol++;
          if(this.$refs[i]['0']['y'] != this.$refs[i+1]['0']['y']){
            break;
          }
        }
        this.columnNumber = this.columnNumber !== calcCol ? calcCol : this.columnNumber;
    },
    checkRowNumber(){
      var calcRow = 0;
      var i = 1;
      while(i < this.channels.length){
          calcRow++;
          if(this.$refs[i]['0']['x'] != this.$refs[i+this.columnNumber]['0']['x']){
            console.log(this.$refs[i]['0']);
            break;
          }
          i+=this.columnNumber;
        }
        this.rowNumber = this.rowNumber !== calcRow ? calcRow : this.rowNumber;
        console.log("sütun sayısı : " + this.columnNumber + " satır sayısı :" + this.rowNumber);
    }
```

I am trying to trigger different functions in resize changes but whenever I change the window size, it is giving me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. It gives me the same error when program starts as well. How can I resolve this issue? any kind of help would be appreciated! Nice regards,

Edit : handleResize function and checkColumnNumber works with giving errors.

Comment: `this.$refs[i]['0']` - looks like you're either referring to something before it's initialized, or accessing it wrong. What's `refs[i]`?

Comment: this.$refs[i] gives the following output : https://i.imgur.com/UpMPRqo.png.

Comment: Try `this.$refs[i][0]`, the 0 without quotes

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: `['0']` is more tedious way to write `[0]` but they are the same, there shouldn't be a difference. The error means that one of arrays that use `['0']` is undefined. There's even no template. Currently only you are able to debug it. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . But a starting point for you is that refs shouldn't be accessed in `created`. Use `mounted`.

Comment: Using mounted didn't fix my issue either. I still gives the exact same error.

Comment: Any way, created definitely should be changed to mounted, this is the only fix that can be suggested here. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. There's a lot of things going on in your code, if you can't debug it, let other users do this. See the comment above and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask